# Using a named view in a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

After i injection $location in directive, part of my templateUrl not loading more.

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('amVideos', amVideos);

amVideos.$inject = ['$location', '$rootScope'];
function amVideos($location, $rootScope){

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/partial/videos.html',
        replace: true,
        link: amVideosLink
    };

    return directive;

    function amVideosLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl){
        // i use $location here
    } 
}
```

The part of the template that does not load has ui-view.

```
<div class="large-8 columns" ui-view="amVideos"></div>
```

The remaining functions normally.

If I use the Properties template, it works.

```
template: '<div>code</div>'
```

someone has been there?

Comment: Can you see a request for the template in your browser's *Network* console?

Comment: Yes.

Really just a part of my template is not loaded.

This part contains a ui-view.
<div class="large-8 columns" ui-view="amVideos"></div>

Comment: Check your router settings.. your named view might not have been resolved properly.

Comment: @PSL, i checked my settings. They are correct. Here is: 
    $stateProvider
      .state('video01', {
        url: "/video01",
        views:{
         'amVideos': {
          templateUrl: "assets/templates/views/video01.html"
         }
        }
      })

Comment: The state will have loaded before your directive is compiled and thus, won't be able to find the view in the template

Comment: @Phil, you know how to avoid this?